# Configuring a docker repository as a subdomain in artifactory

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker, subdomain, artifactory

We are trying to set up a docker repository within artifactory version 4.11.1, following is the set up

```
-- Created a local docker repo - docker-local
-- Created a virtual dokcer repo - docker-virtual
-- Created a remote docker repo - docker-hub
-- Configured docker-local to be the default deployment repo
```

We are using a multidomain certificate that supports reverse-proxy.company.com and docker-virtual.reverse-proxy.company.com

The question is 
Should the nginx configuration be set to the following

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443;
server_name docker-virtual.reverse-proxy.company.com reverse-proxy.company.com;
 ..... other confug

}
```

With this set up I expect the lients to connect to the virtual repo

```
docker push docker-virtual.reverse-proxy.company.com/<my-image>
```

Is this a valid set up?
Note that we dont have a wildcard certificate and its not an option.
Does the multidomain certificate need to support the default deployment directory as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can do it that way by having multiple servername statements instead of the wildcard, and then using our wild-card rewrite rule as-is as you suggested.
There is no need to support anything other than the docker-virtual.reverse-proxy.company.com and the reverse-proxy.company.com as the forward from docker-virtual to the local is internal to artifactory.

You could also have separate server statements, which would make it easier to have single domain certs separately.  The docker one would then be:

```
server {
listen 443;  //docker is ssl only
server_name docker-virtual.reverse-proxy.company.com;
 ..... other confug

}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark that is helpful, by the wildcard rewrite rule would be to forward any request at ocker-virtual.reverse-proxy.company.com to be redirected at     rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/$repo/$1/$2;
correct?

Comment: Ah.  My apologies I just realized that that will only work if you have the wild card server name expression
    server_name ~(?<repo>.+)\.artifactory.local
because that's where it extracts the repo variable via regex.  If your DNS only routes that, it would still be safe to put that listen statement in (instead of the docker-virtual.reverse-proxy.company.com), or you can do the separate listen statements as discussed above.

Comment: Hm. So with the multi-domain certificate that supports docker-virtual.reverse-proxy.company.com, the reroute will be /artifactory/api/docker/docker-virtual/$1/$2. Correct? Would the separate listen statements be on the same port? I am confused now

Comment: Alternatively if I still use the server_name expression and then when clients connect to docker-virtual.reverse-proxy.company.com, that will be still parsed by nginx correctly and since the certificate supports docker-virtual.reverse-proxy.company.com as its SAN, the client will still connect to the correct repository. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes /artifactory/api/docker/docker-virtual/$1/$2 works great, or even (since you're defining it down)
^/|v2/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/docker-virtual/v2/$1
Everything is on the default SSL port, is the great advantage of sub-domains
Not sure what you mean by the second comment.  Some sort of rewrite rule is always necessary, but if you want to move that into a separate servername it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful , teh second comment was to confoirm the usage of a multi domain certificate that supports the repo's subdoomain as its SAN.